# how to join two tables without duplicates in either side using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables A and B for joining, with a common column at both tables. But the ID in both the tables are not unique, so it may have multiple rows in each table with same id.

**Table A**:

| OFF_ID | OFF_NAME | YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc_tech | 4yrs |
| 2 | def_tech | 6yrs |
| 3 | ghi_tech | 2yrs |
| 4 | xyz_tech | 10yrs |
| 5 | lmn_tech | 14yrs |

**Table B**:

| ID | NAME | DOB | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | George | 2001 | chennai |
| 1 | paul | 2005 | bangalore |
| 1 | hem | 1997 | mumbai |
| 2 | vasanth | 1997 | kerala |
| 2 | vicky | 1997 | gujarat |
| 3 | narayan | 1997 | kerala |

I require an output in which the multiple row ID should display once and remain empty for other rows.

**output required**:

| OFFICE_ID | OFFICE_NAME | YEAR | ID | NAME | DOB | CITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc_tech | 4yrs | 1 | george | 2001 | chennai |
| - | - | - | 1 | paul | 2005 | bangalore |
| - | - | - | 1 | hem | 1997 | mumbai |
| 2 | def_tech | 6yrs | 2 | vasanth | 1997 | kerala |
| - | - | - | 2 | vicky | 1997 | gujarat |
| 3 | ghi_tech | 2yrs | 3 | narayan | 1997 | kerala |
| 4 | xyz_tech | 10yrs | - | - | - | - |
| 5 | lmn_tech | 14yrs | - | - | - | - |

it will be helpful for me if i get query as  mysql query.
Thanks in advance.**

Comment: The id in table a looks unique. Table b looks like a disaster

Comment: Where are you going to use the query result?

Comment: MySQL is not really good at this type of thing. It can be achieved but the end result of the query  is not that pretty, especially in a situation where hard-coding values should be avoided. To make a point, [see this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=158cee68f03138c74f1d07b53bffd491)

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right, the output you want as described in your last code block can hardly be achieved via mysql. Where do you want to output it? When you loop over your output, you can take care of it at that point.

Comment: I came across some posts that relates with your reply. it can be achieved with sql server using full join. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```